# Need to get the last 3 elements Django-Queryset

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-queryset

Need to get the last 3 elements, but each one separately without using loops in Django-Queryset

I try to get elements with use order_by(-id)[:3], but I need to be able to use each of the elements without “for”

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking, what do you mean you want to use the elements without "for"? Can you give an example of what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go for this one:

```py
queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
item_minus_3, item_minus_2, item_minus_1 = queryset[len(queryset)-3:]
```

This is a workaround because "Negative indexing is not supported"